# Building an iOS counterpart to an existing Android app using Firebase as a backend. How to test most efficiently

Tags: ios, firebase

My brother developed an Android app that is using Firebase as a backend/database. The app is developed in Java.

I am trying to develop the app for iOS in Swift.

The app is available for Android for the last two years, and it has more than 2 thousand active users. So as you can understand, there are a lot of data stored in Firebase.

This is the first time I try to develop an iOS app on existing data and with a pre-defined database structure. Apparently making tests on the production Firebase data is a bad idea, so any ideas on how I should tackle this?

Also, provided that the database export size is around 8GB, is there a way that I can only export the database structure with no data? Or with data from a specific timeframe? I really don't want to pay double for production and test unless there is no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to develop an app without disrupting your users, is to set up a separate project. Usually I call mine something like `{projectname}-dev` or `{projectname}-puf`, to indicate the relation with `projectname`.

Both Firebase databases (Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore) are schemaless. So there is no way to copy the schema to your development project, because there is no schema to begin with. But often part of your business rules are encoded in the security rules of the database, which you can (and definitely should) port tothe development project.

For getting some data into your development project, I prefer to not have actual user data in my development project. So I typically start with dummy data, either entered through the Firebase console, but more commonly by running some custom node scripts.

If you want to backport specific data from the database for *testing* (which is more common for me than for development), I'd start with a backup of your database, then trim that data down on your development machine, and insert it into the database through its API.